# Example of a function continuous at only one point.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ that is continuous at precisely one point?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60050/find-a-function-f-mathbbr-to-mathbbr-that-is-continuous-at-precisely-o)

I want to know some example of a continuous function which is continuous at exactly one point.
We know that $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ is continuous everywhere except at $x=0$. But i think this in reverse manner but i dont get any example. So please help me out!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

One standard example is the function

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
x,&\text{if }x\in\Bbb Q\\
0,&\text{if }x\in\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q\;.
\end{cases}$$

That is, $f(x)=x$ if $x$ is rational, and $f(x)=0$ if $x$ is irrational. This function is continuous only at $x=0$.

**Added:** The same basic idea can be used to build a function that is continuous at any single specified point. With a little more ingenuity, you can use it to get, for instance, a function that is continuous just at the integers:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
\sin\pi x,&\text{if }x\in\Bbb Q\\
0,&\text{if }x\in\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q\;.
\end{cases}$$

This works because $\sin\pi x=0$ if and only if $x\in\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Does this example have a name?

Comment: @Lucas: Not to my knowledge.

Comment: How does this work if we can find a rational number between any two real numbers?

Comment: Just to be sure, this would work as well if you would switch the definition, right? Namely f(x) = 0 if x is rational, and f(x) = x if x is irrational.

Comment: @TStancek: Belatedly answering a question that I apparently missed at the time, yes, that would also work.

Answer (score 13):

Just take something like the *Dirichlet function*:

$$f : \mathbb R \ni x \mapsto \begin{cases} x&\text{if}\; x\in \mathbb Q\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Then $f$ is continuous only at $x=0$.

Comment: This is not what is commonly called the Dirichlet function, which goes $Dir: x \mapsto \begin{cases} \color{red}{1} \text{ if } x \in \mathbb Q \\ 0 \text{ else} \end{cases}$. So your function is $x \cdot Dir(x)$. Still, great example.