# Limits of function challenge

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

My professor asked me to give an example of a function $f$ defined on real numbers such that $f$ has a limit at $x=5$ only.
Could any one help me to find that example.

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170226/example-of-a-function-continuous-at-only-one-point) isn’t quite a duplicate, but it’s close enough that the answers can be adapted to your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
|x-5|,  & \text{if $x$ is rational} \\
0,      & \text{if $x$ is irrational}
\end{cases}$$

Any interval around any real value $x$ contains both rational and irrational numbers. If $x\ne 5$, the first case in my definition is non-zero and greater than a given value (such as $\frac{|x-5|}2$) in a sufficiently small interval around $x$.

So, if $x\ne 5$, any interval contains points (irrational ones) for which $f(x)$ is zero, and other points (rational ones) that are away from zero. So $f(x)$ does not exist there.

However, at $x=5$, the limit of $f(x)$ for rational numbers is zero, as well as for the irrational numbers. Therefore the limit of $f(x)$ exists there and is zero.

I tried to keep this explanation clear and informal, but a formal proof should be easy given all this.