# Continuity of Dirichlet Function

Tags: continuity

I am confused if the dirichlet function is continuous at 0 or nowhere continuous.
This answer on MSE says it's continuous at 0 [Example of a function continuous at only one point.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170226/example-of-a-function-continuous-at-only-one-point)
The Wikipedia page says it's nowhere continuous: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_function
what's the answer?

Comment: The  function from that example is **not** the Dirichlet function.

Comment: I've added a comment to the second (not the accepted) answer on the MSE page you link to, which wrongly calls its example the Dirichlet function. Your main learning outcome should be to read closely and realize that the two links talked about two different functions.

Comment: Thank you! Feel really stupid for missing that